# Navigation bar didn't show after first run

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using [this library](https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer) to implement menu in my app. If I delete the app and run it, it shows the navigation bar on home page successfully. But if I quit the app without logging out and run it again it didn't show the navigation bar.
 Now I understand the structure of `NavigationController` how it is a stack of `ViewControllers`.
 Here is what I'm doing in the `AppDelegate.m` in order to make my `HomeViewController` my `RootViewController` if user haven't logged out of the account.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:USERID] == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"User is not logged in");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:USERID]);

        HomeViewController *loginController= (HomeViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"]; 
        self.window.rootViewController=loginController;
    }
return YES;
}
```

and here is what I'm doing in `viewDidLoad` of my `HomeViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; self.rootNav = (CCKFNavDrawer *)self.navigationController;
    [self.rootNav setCCKFNavDrawerDelegate:self];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Recent Posts";
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

Also as it was mentioned in the demo of the [library](https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer) I'm using `CCKFNavDrawer` as my Class for my `NavigationController`.
I think I've share enough that explains my problem. Let me know if there is more info required. So, what should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you are making your `UIViewController` as rootController. But if you want to see the navigation bar at the top, you need to instantiate `UINavigationController`  and init with the rootViewController which is your `HomeViewController`.

**Note:** You need to make your `UINavigationController` as root view controller , not your `HomeViewController`

**Edit:**

```
     HomeViewController *loginController= (HomeViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
     CCKFNavDrawer *navController = (CCKFNavDrawer *)[[CCKFNavDrawer alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController]; 
self.window.rootViewController=navController;
```

Comment: I tried this but it crashes the app. If you can see the my `ViewDidLoad` method there is a `Delegate` called `setCCKFNavDrawerDelegate` which is setting `HomeViewController` to `rootNav`. Where `rootNav` is a property of `CCKFNavDrawer` class. See the library link for more information. App crash with this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setCCKFNavDrawerDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: i will look into it!!

Comment: property `navigationController` not found on object of type `AppDelegate` is the error & Sending 'AppDelegate *const__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id< setCCKFNavDrawerDelegate> _Nullable' is the warning I'm getting after writing the updated answer.

Comment: No, there was again an error. You were using `self` in App delegate that was the problem. I've solved this problem, kindly update your answer to `HomeViewController *loginController= (HomeViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        CCKFNavDrawer *navController = (CCKFNavDrawer *)[[CCKFNavDrawer alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
        self.window.rootViewController=navController;` so that I can choose it to be the correct one. Thank You for your help ^_^

Comment: my bad, i didnt relasie nav controller didnt belong to ccknavdraw class